# Different syllabification of /ɪks/ in "excuse" and "sixteen"

Tags: pronunciation

*[Excuse](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/excuse)* is pronounced as /ɪkˈskjuːz/ while *[sixteen](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sixteen)* is pronounced as /sɪksˈtiːn/. You see a ' in the middle of k and s in *excuse* while ' is after both k and s in *sixteen*. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

English generally follows the [Maximum Onset Principle](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48493/what-are-the-syllabification-rules-for-english), which says that syllables are broken so that a consonant is placed into the following syllable as long as it is phonologically valid. So for example, in *excuse,* you cannot place the /k/ in the second syllable because a word (and thus a syllable) cannot start with ksk in English, thus /ɪkˈskjuːz/.

If there is a morpheme boundary in the word, syllables are broken at the morpheme boundary rather than according to the maximum onset principle. This happens with *sixteen*, where the word is broken /sɪksˈtiːn/ rather than /sɪkˈstiːn/, because 'six' and 'teen' are morphemes.

People may not always agree about syllable breaks. For example, in my speech I break *waitress* into syllables as /ˈweɪt.rɛs/, I assume because I perceive 'wait' as a morpheme, but according to dictionaries it is broken /ˈweɪ.trɛs/ (see the discussion in the comments of the linked question).

You could ask why 'ex' doesn't count as a morpheme in *excuse*. I certainly don't know the answer to that, and I'm not sure whether anybody else does, either. But I do pronounce it with a syllable break after the /k/. Whereas *ex-king,* for example, would be pronounced with the break after *ex*.

Answer (score 3):

The sign / ' / is **the primary stress indicator** : it is placed in front of the main stressed syllable of the word.

In  *excuse* the stressed syllable is  */skjuːz/*.
In  *sixteen* - in the pronunciation you give - the stressed syllable is the last one */tiːn/*.

*Sixteen* is often pronounced with a **secondary stress syllable**, shown by the sign /ˌ/ −> */ˌsɪksˈtiːn/* or even with two stressed syllables */ˈsɪksˈtiːn/*, "according to sentence stress" (quoting phonetician [Daniel Jones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Jones_%28phonetician%29)).

You will find the explanation of IPA sounds and symbols on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_chart_for_English).

Comment: Then why it's /ɪkˈskjuːz/ not /ɪks'kjuːz/?

Comment: Both (*/ɪkˈskjuːz/* and */ɪksˈkjuz/* ) are found on wiktionary. I checked in three different pronouncing dictionaries: D. Jones (1967) gives */ɪksˈkjuːz/*, Lewis (1972) and J.C Wells (1990) give */ɪkˈskjuːz/*. Although IPA was not in use in the 18th century [John Walker](http://www.archive.org/details/criticalpronounc00walkuoft) would probably have used Jones's transcription, [see p. 63, §477](http://www.archive.org/stream/criticalpronounc00walkuoft#page/n73/mode/2up). I agree with you */ɪksˈkjuːz/* seems more logical, I wonder if that has to do with the fact we're both non native speakers.

Comment: And the *American Heritage Dictionary* breaks *sixteen* after the /k/, so if they used IPA it would be /sɪkˈstiːn/.

Comment: Both /ɪkˈskjuːz/ and /ɪks'kjuːz/ are allowable, since /kj/ and /skj/ are valid syllable onsets, and /k/ and /ks/ are valid syllable codas. Either one will work, and people vary in their pronunciation and perception of them. On the other hand, the vowel in /ɪk/ in _excuse_ is unstressed, and therefore is often (by many speakers, **always**) reduced to a central vowel [ɨk]; Americans, especially, centralize most unstressed vowels to [ɨ] or [ə]

Comment: This reply does not answer the question, it answers a question that the questioner did not ask (and, I infer, already knew the answer to).

Comment: @John Lawler: except sometimes in *"excuse me"*, pronounced sarcastically.

Answer (score -1):

Usually, we say with stress on last part *eight**EE**n*.

*but*

The *-teen* words are stressed ***EI**ghteen* when they at the beginning of dates, and *eight**EE**n* when they come at the end.
the year 1818 it sound like

***EI**ghteen* *eight**EE**n*

or for 1616
***SIX**teen* *six**TEEN***

Comment: The question is asking about the first part of the word, not the second.